# "Could not find the container for the installed application." When running the application in iPhone Device

Tags: iphone, ios4

I am running my application in iPhone 3G, while running i am geting an alert "Could not find the container for the installed application." I switched off the mobile, I Quit the Xcode, restart the machine. But not able to solve.
Please Suggest

Thankls